# How to execute a command automatically on startup in Chrome OS?

Tags: google-chrome-os

So I am a newbie to programming and was just wondering if I can make a `chromebook`, that's already in developer mode, run a simple `sudo` command on startup without me having to open a terminal or anything and type it out. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, no, this is not possible by design w/out modifying the root filesystem.  and if you do that, your changes will be silently lost on the next upgrade.

your shell does save history, so it would be a few key presses at least ...